# Google tag manger not supporting internet explorer tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have setup TAG and Triggers on one of the website they are working fine on fire fox and chrome browser but  they are not working on Internet explorer .
Even if I am at home page of the website it shows zero active user in real time.

Please what is the issue and what needs to done so that I can track user interaction with website on internet explorer.